# Merge two lines into one and create Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file with data which is not easy to make stucure ready to create dataframe.

```
SFE,     8924,   3,CONV,1,R5.0
 1.267065000E-04 1.267065000E-04 1.267065000E-04 1.267065000E-04
SFE,     8924,   3,CONV,2,R5.0
  761.000000      761.000000      761.000000      761.000000    
SFE,     8925,   3,CONV,1,R5.0
 1.289895000E-04 1.289895000E-04 1.289895000E-04 1.289895000E-04
SFE,     8925,   3,CONV,2,R5.0
  761.000000      761.000000      761.000000      761.000000
```

There are spaces, multispaces, comas and tabs. How to merge 1st and 2nd line together (3rd+4th and so on)?

Desired outcome:

```
SFE,8924,3,CONV,1,R5.0,1.267065000E-04,1.267065000E-04,1.267065000E-04,1.267065000E-04
SFE,8924,3,CONV,2,R5.0,761.000000,761.000000,761.000000,761.000000    
SFE,8925,3,CONV,1,R5.0,1.289895000E-04,1.289895000E-04,1.289895000E-04,1.289895000E-04
SFE,8925,3,CONV,2,R5.0,761.000000,761.000000,761.000000,761.000000
```

and then pandas should have no problem creating the df.

For now I have such a code (file has some text at the beginning, so I read starting in 45line):

```
data=[]
file = open('7HA03_thermal_final_filled.txt', 'r+')
with file as f:
    lines=f.readlines()[45:]
    for line in lines:
        data.append(line)
file.close()
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Tried to play with odds and even lines but still have one column with strings.
Can share more not successful code but I believe there is some easier way to join lines and clear it from different separators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
data = []
with open("7HA03_thermal_final_filled.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for i in range(1, len(content)+1):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            first_line = content[i-2].strip()
            first_line = "".join(first_line.split())
            second_line = content[i-1].strip()
            second_line = " ".join(second_line.split())
            second_line_modified = ",".join(x for x in second_line.strip().split(' '))
            data.append(f'{first_line},{second_line_modified}')
df = pd.DataFrame([string.split(",") for string in data])
```

Comment: Great, this joined lines like i need - only needed add space between lines: data.append(content[i-2].strip() +" "+ content[i-1].strip())  But still it is one column when put into DataFrame. How to change different separators into one accptable by Pandas?

Comment: @Paulina I have modified the code. This exactly matches your desired outcome. Please verify and let me know if you have any further questions:)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now i have combined line with comas only. I will try to separate columns and will let you know soon - need to have a break. Appriciate your help very much.

Comment: When I gain enough reputation I will vote for your answer.

Comment: @Paulina sure, thanks. The separating of the columns is done in the final line of the above code. If you are looking for something different, please let me know. Good luck!

Comment: You're right, i missed last line. Thanks again!